# Spyder IDE: Why does assert not work?

Tags: python, spyder

I'm using Spyder 2.2.0dev on Mac OS (10.7.6), which, as it says on startup, uses Python 2.7.3 (default, Jul 24 2012, 20:20:13).
When I type

```
assert False
```

this should raise an AssertionError, as it does in my normal Python installation. However, in Spyder (both ipyton and the internal console) it does not raise any error. Does this have to be switched on somewhere? Or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assertions are skipped when python is invoked with the `-O` options.  I'm not familiar with spyder, but I would venture that some option is causing your python to be run "optimized"

Because assertions aren't always run, they are not suitible for program flow.  If you want your program to stop at a certain point because a certain condition fails, *raise a meaningful exception inside an `if` suite.*

```
if False:
    raise ValueError("expected True, received", False)
```

Comment: ok thanks for the explanation. I have not been able to find the location in spyder where one can specifiy the python options, but this will very likely be the answer.

Comment: You can check within a Python program whether `-O` was selected by testing `sys.flags.optimize` (http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.flags)

Comment: sys.flags.optimize gives 2, so this answers the question. Thanks!